# ui.bootstrap.datepicker is-open not working in modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I´m using the Bootstrap UI datepicker directive and I´m trying to have an datepicker button that opens the datepicker popup like in the original example but it does not work in a modal window.

See [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zUHqAvx5P9RR86gDi2f?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just change to: `is-open="opened"` to:

```
is-open="$parent.opened"
```

Fixed Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2bSvSZBJ6LcqrsfoYUtS?p=preview)**</kbd>

So relevant snippets of HTML will look like:

```
      <div class="input-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                 datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
                 ng-model="dt"
                 is-open="$parent.opened"
                 ng-required="true"
                 close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button style="height:34px;" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
          <i class="icon-calendar"></i></button> <b><- button not working</b>
          </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: I was scratching my head over this.. Thank you for posting this solution! And how would anyone know to do this!?

Comment: @SoichiHayashi The $parent.xxxx will will prevent the child scope from creating its own property. I think this is is what datepicker does.

Comment: Or something about modals transcluding the scope, yada yada. Not entirely obvious ;-)

Comment: Can i tell you that this doesn't make sense to me at all when I have especially made a separate controller for my modal. Thanks for I have spent 4 hours on this. But, better late than never. You're a Rockstar

Comment: I know I'm a long time after this was written, but is there something that needs to be corrected to make the datepicker's selection actually get returned properly to the main page? (if you try the Plunker, it lets you select a new date and that updates within the modal, but when you click Okay, the main page only ever shows the original date)

Comment: **Answered my own question...** - simply need to change the reference to `ng-model="dt"` to be  `ng-model="$parent.dt"` within the `input`

Comment: @MaximShoustin I actually created an issue on Github about this https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3034 hope they improve the documentation.

Comment: # Maxim Shoustin :I was finding solution.Thanks for posting wonderful solution.

Comment: This is the best solution for ui bootstrap datepicker .

Comment: Not working for me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162169/angular-bootstrap-datepicker-not-opening-on-angular-modal

Answer (score 13):

I had to put a timeout to make it work:

```
function toggleStart($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $timeout(function () {
        vm.isStartOpen = !vm.isStartOpen;
    });
}
```

My template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
        datepicker-popup ng-model="vm.startDate"
        is-open="vm.isStartOpen" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="vm.toggleStart($event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Wrapping the status change in a $timeout fixed this for me, though I'm nto sure why. Something must be slightly screwy in the library code.

Answer (score 8):

datepicker directive creates its own scope which is not accessible outside.So to solve this you can use.

```
$parent.isopen
```

or use some Object property name to avoid prototype Inheritance, like

```
$scope.config.isopen=true;
```

`ng-model="config.isopen"` instead of `ng-model="isopen"`.

Comment: This is far better than the acceted answer.

Comment: this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You also work like that to initialize the date picker by icon.

HTML

```
<p class="input-group" ng-disabled="invoiceDateDisable">
    <input is-open="opened" type="text" datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="Date" datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.open = function () {
    $scope.opened = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an `open` function:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
               datepicker-popup="dd.mm.yyyy"
               ng-model="dt"
               is-open="$parent.opened"
               ng-required="true"
               close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button style="height:34px;" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$parent.opened=!$parent.opened">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i></button> <b><- button not working</b>
        </span>
      </div>
```