# Angular ui bootstrap datepicker in not responding in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

The problem is that when i choose a `date` from the `angular ui bootstrap` `datepicker` once after that when again i choose to set another date then the `datepicker dropdown`  is not leting me choose date.. or simply the datepicker is not working..
These are some screenshots of the datepicker

[image]

[image]

After this when again i click on the input field it doesn't open the datepicker popup..

How to get rid from this problem ?

Can anyone help me to fix this problem....
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to improve your question by adding the code showing how you used the datepicker directive

Comment: @callmekatootie i have used the default code provided by the ui bootstrap

Comment: If you have used default code, then it should work as can be seen in their [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). Since its not working, you clearly are doing something else which you need to describe using your code. Or even better - show that its not working through a plunkr or a fiddle.

Comment: in the documentation the date is disabled and i enabled the date and i think in the documentation we cannot choose the date that's why its working

Comment: You need to provide some code snippet, its your code issue not the plugin. Create some jsfiddle or plunker link, if you want the solution.

Comment: i got the answer of my question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212813/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-is-open-not-working-in-modal/20213924#20213924.)