# Angular directive issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

For few days I was trying to debug why my directive doesn't work. No event has been fired when I press a button. Finally I found which line breaks everything!

Inside template html I have line `datepicker-popup ng-model="{{model}}" min-date="{{minDate}}" is-open="{{isOpened}}"` if I remove it everything works well. But it is essential part in my custom directive and I want to keep it. I assume problem is that I am using directive inside custom directive?

Could you please help me to identify problem and find a correct solution?

Thanks for any help!

Directive:

```
(function(){

    function directive(){
        return {
            scope :{
                model:'=model',
                minDate:'=minDate',
                isOpened:'=isOpened'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        };
    };

    app.directive('myDirective', directive);

})();
```

controller:

```
(function(){

    function Controller($scope) {
        $scope.open = function() {
            alert('HELLO');
        };
    app.controller('Ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

template html:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="{{model}}" min-date="{{minDate}}" is-open="{{isOpened}}" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: most of those attributes don't accept `{{}}` in the expression

Comment: even if I remove attributes but leave `datepicker-popup` it still doesn't work and all the way around.

Comment: create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Did you see this? I think this is the answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212813/ui-bootstrap-datepicker-is-open-not-working-in-modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, you don't need the curly braces in your template because it's a two way binding.

The problem with your click function is probably the isolated scope of your custom directive.
If you'd like to have the `open` method in your main controller you could pass it to the isolated scope.

Please find below a demo of your directive or here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/LsmL0rrt/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('mainController', Controller)
    .directive('customDir', Directive);

function Directive() {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            minDate: '=',
            isOpened: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html',
        //controller: 'Ctrl'
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.open = function() {
                console.log('open popup now!!');
                $scope.isOpened = true;
            };
        }
    };
}

function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.open = function () {
        alert('HELLO'); // not called becasue of isolated scope of custom directive
    };
    $scope.dateModel = {
        date: new Date(),
        min: new Date()
    };
    $scope.isOpened = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/datepicker/datepicker.html">
        <fieldset>
    <div class='input-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="" ng-model="model" min-date="minDate" is-open="isOpened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open()" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
    </script>
    
    <custom-dir model="dateModel.date" min-date="dateModel.min" is-opened="isOpened"></custom-dir>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer since you provide way more information than I did.

Comment: Thanks. The fiddle took some time to create that's why I was a bit late with my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define your directive's scope properties with a *=* symbol, you don't need to use *{{}}* in your views.

Remove the *{{}}* from your view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="model" min-date="minDate" is-open="isOpened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope) more info regarding directive's scope properties using *=*, *&* and *@*.